# How to block a single cell for editing without block the column

Tags: angular, ag-grid, editing

I have a table with 3 columns:
[location] [dateStart] [dateEnd]
I want the user select a `location` and after that select `dateStart` and `dateEnd`. For that I want disable the cells of `dateStart` and `dateEnd`.

```
onCellValueChanged: (params) => {
      if (this.locationIsMandatory) {
            if (params.newValue) {
                  params.columnApi.getColumn('dateStart').getColDef().editable = true;
                  params.columnApi.getColumn('dateEnd').getColDef().editable = true;
      }
}
```

This code blocks the columns but in all the rows of the table and I just want it in the row what the user is modifying.

Regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the editable column definition into a function which returns `true` or `false` based on your need.

```
editable: function(params) {
    if (condition) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: you can get the row data and column data from `params`